# Invalid URI. The hostname cannot be parsed

Tags: asp.net, uri

I'm trying to  get the folder path of another website of mine which is hosted on a ssl.

This is how I'm trying to get it but it is throwing me an error "Invalid URI. The hostname cannot be parsed"

```
Dim uriPath As String = "https:\\www.abc.com\myfolder\"
Dim localPath As String = (New Uri(uriPath)).AbsolutePath
```

Can anyone suggest me how to acheive this ?

Comment: use different slash (`/`) instead

Comment: @IlyaBursov-Thanks for your answer..It worked well :)